# Implementation of the latest "Lookahead Optimizer" paper in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

The lookahead optimizer is proposed very recently (https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.08610), and seems very promising (even Hinton is one of the authors!).

Therefore, I wonder how to **implement it in keras**? I think many people may need the answer to this question, because we want to plug it into our existing code and it may produce better results.

I am new in keras, so any help would be truly appreciated. Thanks!

p.s. source code of existing optimizers: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py

Comment: If I ask imperfectly, I would appreciate it if anyone could inform me s.t. I can improve. Thanks!

Comment: your question is too general: how to implement? I suggest you to start with code and paper and if you will have some issue, please ask question regarding the implementation process.

Comment: I glanced the paper, didn't read it in details, according to the idea, the algorithm maintain two sets of weights. Fast and slow, during optimization, you update fast weights just like normal optimization such as SGD or Adam, then after a synchronization period, let's say N iteration, you update slow weights with a transformation from fast weights (in the paper it says imputation if in remember correctly). So you just manually set a set of weights through fit() and use the final weights as the weights for your model.

Comment: @fzyzcjy Even though an implementation may be useful to many people, StackOverflow is not a "please write this code for me" kind of site. If you have a specific implementation detail that you're stuck on, please provide more detail, otherwise this is too broad.

Comment: @pkpnd CharlesChow Paddy Thanks for your advice! I will try to write the code as soon as I get back to home from a bussiness trip! So shall I answer my own question after writing the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For demonstrating the concept behind, one might implement the Lookahead Optimizer in a Keras callback, see my implementation here https://github.com/kpe/params-flow/blob/master/params_flow/optimizers/lookahead.py

```py
def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    self.count += 1
    if self.slow_weights is None:
        self.slow_weights = self.model.trainable_weights
    else:
        if self.count % self.k == 0:
            slow_ups, fast_ups = [], []
            for fast, slow in zip(self.model.trainable_weights,
                                  self.slow_weights):
                slow_ups.append(K.update(slow, slow + self.alpha * (fast - slow)))
                fast_ups.append(K.update(fast, slow))
            K.batch_get_value(slow_ups)
            K.batch_get_value(fast_ups)
```

What this does is conceptually embarrassingly simple - every `k` updates the weights would be moved halfway (`alpha=0.5`) towards what their value was `k` iterations ago.

**N.B.** The above implementation might not work that well on a GPU or TPU, as the `slow_weights` copy of the weights would probably get updated on the CPU (and moving the weights takes time).

Comment: p.s. There is an official implementation in tensorflow now https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/Lookahead

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT (2020.03):** There is an *official* implementation in tensorflow! https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/Lookahead

---

Today when I want to start implementing it, I found that somebody has already done it! (Of course, when I asked this question, it cannot be Googled.)

Here is the link: https://github.com/bojone/keras_lookahead
(For the non-Chinese readers, I have slightly modified the repo: https://github.com/fzyzcjy/keras_lookahead.)

And the usage is like:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-3), loss='mse') # Any optimizer
lookahead = Lookahead(k=5, alpha=0.5) # Initialize Lookahead
lookahead.inject(model) # add into model
```

Looking into his code, the core of the implementation is the modification of the `model.train_function`, i.e. `model.train_function = ...`, to achieve the two sets of updates.

In addition, it seems that the "hacking" trick of the repo comes from the following article (judging from his code and comments): https://kexue.fm/archives/5879/comment-page-1 (Sorry it is a non-English page)